# How to pass javascript variable from laravel controller to vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to build a page on `Laravel 5.4` which contains few data which needs to be manipulated and then sent across the views. My view contains components of the `vuejs v2.0`. I want those data to be implemented in the components. I tried using the `laracasts PHP Vars to JS transformer` but unable to get it. I followed the steps by placing `"laracasts/utilities": "~2.0"` in my `composer.json` then I added the serviceprovider as mentioned in the documentation, I published the vendor and added the following in `config/javascript.php`,

```
'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'Nitseditor.show',
```

I'm having a dynamic views folder which is currently inside my `Nitseditor\home\resources\views` Now in my controller I'm having following codes:

```
public function show()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'age' => 29
    ]);
    return view(Nitseditor.show);
}
```

Now first of all it was throwing an error as I see that it was including `use MongoDB\BSON\Javascript;` then I removed and tried using `use JavaScript`

Now in the `app.js` file which is present in my asset folder, I'm including each components and trying to do `console.log(foo);` but its throwing an error `foo` not defined.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this depending on what you are trying to achieve and how your project is set up. The simplest way is to make a request to your controller from inside your component that returns `json`. `Laravel 5.4` comes with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) so you can use that:

```
methods: {
  getData(){
    axios.get('/controller/route')
    .then(response => {
      // set your variables from the response
      this.myData = response.data;
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
},
data(){
  return {
    myData: {}
  }
}
```

If you need child components to access the data then you would need to put that in the parent and pass myData" using `props`.

You could also create a directive and pass your variable down directly from your blade template:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
});
```

Then you would just need to do:

```
<div v-init:vars="{foo: 'foo', age: 29}"></div>
```

And pass `vars` as props to any component that needs them:

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3e05qwLh/

If you have multiple descendants that rely on your variables you will probably want to look at using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org).

Comment: can you please explain me how to do this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972797/how-to-do-filters-in-vue-js

Answer (score -1):

Dunno if it helps but I use this method for passing variables to javascript:

```
// in master layout (head section)
<meta name="foo" content="{{ $foo }}">

// in javascript (included or in the template)
foo = $('meta[name=foo]').attr('content');
```

If you have javascript in the blade template you can use directly this method:

```
foo = "{{ $foo }}";
```

Comment: You are using jQuery even though the author asked for plain javascript + vue. You should add the plain javascript syntax for accessing the meta data

Comment: Nobody ask for "plain" javascript, and laravel 5.4 default installation include jQuery, see there https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js So your comment is not really appropriate