# how to do filters in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

i am new to vue.js.so i want  to apply a filter thing in my project.i tried to do this from past 2 to 3 days..but i couldn't..can any one help me how to do this..

I have 3 input boxes one is experience,expected_ctc,and profile_role depending on these 3 i want to display the results..

Here is my js page:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      page: 0,
      itemsPerPage: 3,
    }
 },
 components: { Candidate },
  methods: {
  //custom method bound to page buttons
  setPage(page) {
    this.page = page-1;
    this.paginedCandidates = this.paginate()
  },
  paginate() {
    return this.filteredCandidates.slice(this.page * this.itemsPerPage, this.page * this.itemsPerPage + this.itemsPerPage)
  },
 },


 computed: {
  //compute number of pages, we always round up (ceil)
  numPages() { 
    console.log(this.filteredCandidates) 
    return Math.ceil(this.filteredCandidates.length/this.itemsPerPage); 
  },
  filteredCandidates() {
    //filter out all candidates that have experience less than 10
    const filtered = window.data.candidates.filter((candidate) => {
      if(candidate.experience === 5) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    })
    console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
  },
  paginedCandidates() {
    return this.paginate()
  }
 }
});
```

here is my buttons from view page:

```
<div class="container">

<b>Experience:</b><input type="text" v-model="experience" placeholder="enter experience">

<b>Expected CTC:</b><input type="text" v-model="expected_ctc" placeholder="enter expected ctc">

<b>Profile Role:</b><input type="text" v-model="profile_role_id" placeholder="enter role">


<input type="button" name="search" value="search" >

</div>
```

Can anyone help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Quite a lot of questions: What does the Candidate component look like. Where do you use it? Where are the data definitions for the shown v-model bindings? Why is data bound to the window?!? If you want to use vue filtering this seems a little weird.

Comment: actually i don't know how to use v-model in the vue.js page fro the filter.....i just created..v-model in the input box..

Comment: i will edit my question..there u can see..how my candidate component look like..

Comment: where does your data come from? where do you load it? why is it on the window property? And maybe even more relevant: Where do you even use the candidate component?

Comment: it is coming from the vue page..i import candidate.vue in my js page import Candidate from './components/Candidate.vue';

Comment: what vue page? I only see that you have a setPage which again takes data from the window - why don't you put the data directly into your component or app ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144223/discussion-between-frank-provost-and-bharathi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's start with a smaller example. Lets say you have "Candidates" one one candidate might look like

```
{ 
  name: 'John Doe',
  expected_ctc: 'A',
  experience: 'B',
  profile_role_id: 1
}
```

From your current state I'd say you have all candidates in an array returned by laravel. Let's say we're in your current template where you have your vue app

```
<div id="app">
   <!-- lets start with one filter (to keept it clean) -->
   <input type="text" v-model="experienceSearch"/>

   <ul class="result-list">
     <li v-for="result in candidatelist">{{ result.name }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And now to the script

```
// always init your v-model bound props in data
// usually you wouldn't take the candidates from the window prop. However, to keep it easy for you here I will stick to this
data: function() {
  return {
     experienceSearch: '',
     candidates: window.data.candidates
  }
},

// the list that is displayed can be defined as computed property. It will re-compute everytime your input changes
computed: {
  candidatelist: function() {
     // now define how your list is filtered
     return this.candidates.filter(function(oCandidate) {
        var matches = true;

        if (this.experienceSearch) {
           if (oCandidate.experience != this.experienceSearch) {
              matches = false;
           }
        }

        // here you can define conditions for your other matchers

        return matches;
     }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

General steps:

- all candidates are in data -> candidates
- relevant (filtered) candidates are represented by the computed prop candidatelist
- inputs are bound with v-model to **EXISTING** data prop definitions

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sLLk4u2a/

(Search is only exact and Case Sensitive)

Comment: And i have another doubt..if it is one condition it's working..how to apply for multiple conditions..

Comment: Define them at `// here you can define conditions for your other matchers` this is why I've used the matches variable. You can check each condition one by one here. Basically it is an AND condition. If you want and "or" condition just set matches to false on default and change it to true on match.

Comment: yup..it's working..thank you..thanks a lot..@Frank Provost

Comment: i want to give a button after 3 filters..then only i want to display the results..can you please explain me how to do that..

Comment: instead of putting the candidateList in a computed prop you can define a "candidateList" array in the data section and copy the function that is currently used in the computed prop as a method. Then you call the method as you press the button. Don't forget to change `return matches` in the bottom line to `this.candidateList = matches`

Comment: this is working fine..but when i apply this code...the results is showing in console..and not showing in view..and my pagination also not working..if it possible can you please tel me where i mistaken,,i will share my code..

Comment: you should open a new question for this.